# Transform flat object into nested structure by keys

Tags: javascript

Is there any recommended way in Javascript that can parse the keys of an object to transform it into something nested? Here is an example:

Transform this:

```
{
  "person[profile][0][degree_type]": "Bachelor's",
  "person[profile][0][college_name]": "AI Miami International University of Art and Design",
  "person[profile][0][business_school_name]": "",
  "person[profile][0][law_school_name]": "",
  "person[profile][0][other_school_name]": "",
  "person[profile][0][undergraduate_major_name]": "Anthropology",
  "person[profile][0][max_gpa]": "",
  "person[profile][1][degree_type]": "",
  "person[profile][1][college_name]": ""
}
```

To this:

```
"person": {
  "profile": [
    {
      "degree_type": "Bachelor's",
      "college_name": "AI Miami International University of Art and Design",
      "business_school_name": "",
      "law_school_name": "",
      "other_school_name": "",
      "undergraduate_major_name": "",
      "max_gpa": ""
    },
    {
      .....
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have some code in one of my Angular libraries, formFor, that does a similar parsing. Not exactly the same, but I bet you could fork it, tweak it, and get what you're looking for :) https://github.com/bvaughn/angular-form-for/blob/master/source/services/nested-object-helper.js

Comment: Give me a few moments and I'll see if I can do the fork/mods for you :)

Comment: Seems like a really bad idea to create an object that holds keys that are strings, but should be objects/arrays instead

Comment: I suspect his example is actually a typo, and that there should be a second object in the person.profile array.

Comment: Why do you want to parse only [0] and not [1]?

Comment: @adeneo Keys are from forms created by Rails. I didn't create it.

Comment: [asking for a software library recommendation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is off topic so I would remove that part from your question. Also your question should be specific that has a single answer. Asking for "recommendations" is broad and primarily opinion based.

Comment: I have coded something similar. If you think you can replace the bracket syntax with the point synax, eg: `car[brand]` to `car.brand` you'll be able to use my code: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/59162/8585 or you can go straight to a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/renatoargh/88U3N/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go! :) That was fun.

```
var flatObj = {
  "person[profile][0][degree_type]": "Bachelor's",
  "person[profile][0][college_name]": "AI Miami International University of Art and Design",
  "person[profile][0][business_school_name]": "",
  "person[profile][0][law_school_name]": "",
  "person[profile][0][other_school_name]": "",
  "person[profile][0][undergraduate_major_name]": "Anthropology",
  "person[profile][0][max_gpa]": "",
  "person[profile][1][degree_type]": "",
  "person[profile][1][college_name]": ""
};

var parse = function(data, string, value) {
  if (string.indexOf("]") >= 0) {
    var match = string.charAt(0) != "[" ? string.match(/([^\[]+)\[/) : string.match(/\[([^\]]+)\]/);
    var key = match[1];

    var token = key + ']';
    var index = string.indexOf(token) + token.length;

    if (!data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      data[key] = isNaN(key) ? {} : [];
    }

    if (index >= string.length) {
      data[key] = value;
    } else {
      parse(data[key], string.substring(index), value);
    }
  }
};

var data = {};

for (var prop in flatObj) {
  parse(data, prop, flatObj[prop]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ES5 [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) methods, you could have something like:

```
var data = {
  "person[profile][0][degree_type]": "Bachelor's",
  "person[profile][0][college_name]": "AI Miami International University of Art and Design",
  "person[profile][0][business_school_name]": "",
  "person[profile][0][law_school_name]": "",
  "person[profile][0][other_school_name]": "",
  "person[profile][0][undergraduate_major_name]": "Anthropology",
  "person[profile][0][max_gpa]": "",
  "person[profile][1][degree_type]": "",
  "person[profile][1][college_name]": ""
};

var object = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(result, item) {
  var o = result;
  var leaf = item.match(/\w+/g).reduce(function(current, next) {
    o[current] = o[current] || (String(next >>> 0) === next ? [] : {});
    o = o[current];
    return next;
  });
  o[leaf] = data[item];
  return result;
}, {});
```

The zero-fill right shift operator (`>>>`) is the used to mimic the internal `ToUint32` operation in JS, in order to ensure that a string is a valid array's index, otherwise is considered a property (e.g. `"1.5"` can be parsed as number, but is not a valid array's index). See [ECMAScript specs section 15.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4)

Comment: Beautiful! Some neat stuff in there!

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely overkill, but here's an example on how you could do it by lexing your key syntax with a traditionnal lexer. The advantage would be having good error reporting as well as easily being able to enhance the syntax.

Here's an example of the kind of syntax error you could get with something like:

`expandKeys({"person[profile][0]degree_type]": "Bachelor's" });`

*`Uncaught Error: invalid key 'person[profile][0]degree_type]'; expected '[' and instead saw 'd' at character 18`*

```js
/*jshint esnext:true*/
var expandKeys = (function () {
    'use strict';
    
    var LBRACK = '[',
        RBRACK = ']';
    
    return function (obj) {
        var result = {};
        
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (k) {
            var tokens = tokensFrom(k), 
                o = result,
                t = nextFrom(tokens, k).value;
            
            while (t) {
                let next = nextFrom(tokens, k);                
                if (next.done) o[t] = obj[k];
                else if (o.hasOwnProperty(t)) o = o[t];
                else o = o[t] = isInt(+next.value)? [] : {};
                t = next.value;
            }
        });
                
        return result;
    };
    
    function isInt(val) {
        return val >>> 0 === val;
    }
    
    function nextFrom(gen, k) {
        try {
            return gen.next();
        } catch (e) {
            throw new Error("invalid key '" + k + "'; " + e.message);
        }
    }
    
function *tokensFrom(input) {
        var state = prop, 
            i = 0, 
            c = input[0],
            token;
        
        while (state = state()) yield token;
        
        yield token;
        
        function prop() {
            var p = '';
            
            while (c && c !== LBRACK && c !== RBRACK) {
                p += c;
                consume();
            }
            
            if (!p) error('expected a property name');
            
            token = p;
            
            return c? surroundedProp : null;
        }
        
        function surroundedProp() {
            match(LBRACK);
            prop();
            match(RBRACK);
            return c? surroundedProp : null;
        }
        
        function match(char) {
            if (c === char) consume();
            else error("expected '" + char + "' and instead saw '" + (c || '') + "'");
        }
        
        function consume() {
            return c = input[++i];
        }
        
        function error(msg) {
            throw new Error(msg + ' at character ' + i);
        }
    }
    
})();

var data = {
    "person[profile][0][degree_type]": "Bachelor's",
    "person[profile][0][college_name]": "AI Miami International University of Art and Design",
    "person[profile][0][business_school_name]": "",
    "person[profile][0][law_school_name]": "",
    "person[profile][0][other_school_name]": "",
    "person[profile][0][undergraduate_major_name]": "Anthropology",
    "person[profile][0][max_gpa]": "",
    "person[profile][1][degree_type]": "",
    "person[profile][1][college_name]": ""
};


var result = expandKeys(data),
    resultJson = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2),
    pre = document.createElement('pre');

pre.textContent = resultJson;

document.body.appendChild(pre);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using ramda.js, this is a pretty small bit of code

```js
const obj = {
  'nestedObject[first]': 10,
  'nestedObject[second]': 5,
  'nestedArray[0]': 3.1,
  'nestedArray[1]': 3.2,
  'param': 5
}

const deFlatten = (object) => {
  const parsePath = R.pipe(R.match(/(\w+)/g), R.map(R.ifElse(R.pipe(R.unary(parseInt), isNaN), R.identity, R.unary(parseInt))));
  const reducer = (acc, flatKey) => R.set(R.lensPath(parsePath(flatKey)), object[flatKey])(acc);
  return R.pipe(R.keys, R.reduce(reducer, {}))(object);
};

console.log(deFlatten(obj));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@0.25.0/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```